# How do I add the number to the variable in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I need to guess the 4-digit code by this program, but I have no idea why it doesn't work.
I tried to use two for loops to guess all of the numbers from 0 to 9 for 4 digits.
However, the program doesn't print anything.
I wonder how can I add the current value `x` to the variable `result`.

```js
function start() {
  var secretPasscode = generateRandomPasscode();

  // Write your code here
  var result = "";
  //Loop through for the secretPasscode's length
  for(var i = 0; i < secretPasscode.length; i++){
      
    //Put numbers from 0 to 9
    for(var x = 0; x < 10; x++){
      result = "";
      var currNum = x;
      //If the current number is right, store it to the result
      if(currNum == secretPasscode.charAt(i)){
        result += x;
      }else{
        result = result;
      }
    }
  }
  return result;
  println(result);
}

function isCorrect(guessCode, correctCode) {
  return guessCode == correctCode;
}

// Generates a random 4 digit passcode and returns it as a String
function generateRandomPasscode() {
  var randomPasscode = "";
  
  for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    var randomDigit = Randomizer.nextInt(0, 9);
    randomPasscode += randomDigit;
  }
  return randomPasscode;
}
```

Comment: Nothing after a `return` in a function gets executed.

Comment: **error** `Randomizer` object doesn't exist

Comment: `Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);      // returns a random integer from 0 to 9` to make a random number 0 to 9. Also, use `console.log` not println.

Comment: Nevermind guys. I solved the problem! Thank you so much

Comment: @Songdnwn If the solution would be helpful to others, post it as an answer.